# Retaining Ownership of an 'Approval' Indicator Coin

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I want to use some form of crypto-currency/blockchain algorithm to represent the notion of "*endorsement*", in the sense of approval.  One approach is to have a coin that you can give to a recipient, while retaining ownership and control of the coin, so that you can withdraw it at any time and give it to someone else.

Is there such a thing? Is there any reason why you can't do this with a blockchain?  What are the issues?

Comment: You can do this with a block chain. The easiest way is pro bably to form a payment that can be claimed by either of two public keys. One of them is yours used to take the coins back, the other of which has no corresponding private key but is used to indicate what you're endorsing.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchwartz,  do you know any implementations of such a scheme, where I could find out more?